# Action script layout of options

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am writing a multiple choice quiz using AS3.  And, I want to display answer options in columns of 2 0r 3 such as:

```
 A) Answer A B) Answer B  C) Answer C
 D) Answer D E) Answer E
```

I use this to accomplish the layout,

```
answerTextField.x=(j%3) * 200 ;
answerTextField.y=  questionName.y + 20 + ((j % 2) * 20) ;
```

but it produces

```
 A) Answer A E) Answer E  C) Answer C
 D) Answer D B) Answer B
```

How can we solve this problem or is there any other way to accomplish the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved:

```
answerTextField.y=  questionName.y + 20 + (int(j / 2) * 20) ;
```